# what is mean Dotted line + black triangle in UML？

Tags: design-patterns, uml

what is mean Dotted line + black triangle in UML？
 [image: this pic for problem]

Answer (score 2):

That notation does not exist in UML

It seems the author of the diagram actually meant a dependency, for which the notation is slightly different:

[image]

Comment: that notation can be used for reply message ;-) 
However I do not remember having already seen it used (and incidentally I do not propose it in [BoUML](https://bouml.fr/doc/index_sequencediagram.html)

Answer (score 1):

> what is mean Dotted line + black triangle in UML？

In the given context the notation in invalid, probably it is a dependency (array head must be open)

---

That notation anyway exist and corresponds to a reply Message represented by a dashed line with either an open or filled arrow head. (chap 17.4.4.1 of formal/2017-12-05)

Comment: It's also the notation for a flow in ArchiMate. Sometimes tools implementing multiple languages can be misinterpreted and you end up with mixed models. Could be that.

Comment: @muszeo this is not a normalized notation, for _flow_ whose do not use dashed line, and even not for an InformationFlow (_An InformationFlow is represented using the same notation as Dependency, with the keyword «flow» adorning its dashed line).

Comment: Hey @bruno, sorry the flow I was talking about is in ArchiMate not UML. Some tools do both language sets (e.g. Sparx EA) but don't stop you from mixing the languages together.